# Is there a common way to open "svn-status" or "magit" depending on current buffers system?

Tags: git, vc, svn

before I sit down and reinvent the wheel for me:

I'm working with svn and git in different projects. Is there already an existing way to start `svn-status` or `magit`, depending on the vcs that is used for the file in the current buffer? Maybe some of the vc-* commands?

Thanks,
Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```el
(defun open-status ()
  (interactive)
  (if vc-mode
      (if (string-match "^ Git" (substring-no-properties vc-mode))
          (magit-status)
        (if (string-match "^ SVN" (substring-no-properties vc-mode))
            (call-interactively 'svn-status )
          (if (string-match "^ HG" (substring-no-properties vc-mode))
              (ahg-status)
            )))
    (message "not a project file")))
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! `(svn-status ".")` didn't match my needs, so I replaced it with `( call-interactively 'svn-status )` and now I have just what I needed :)

Comment: True, much better... edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

I came up with something like this.

```el
(defun vc-status ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((backend (vc-responsible-backend default-directory)))
    (cond ((equal 'Git backend) (magit-status))
          ((equal 'Hg backend) (ahg-status)))))
```

Comment: Nice, getting the backend like this looks a bit "cleaner"...